# Difference between "has + verbed" and "had + verbed"

Tags: difference, verbs, present-perfect, past-perfect

This is something which came up in my [last question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7978).

As far as I know "had + verb" is done (started & finished) in the past. What's about "has + verb"?
Can anyone please explain me the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:
The present perfect is used to describe an action which causes a present state.
The past perfect is used to describe an action which caused a past state.

---

LONG ANSWER:
The verb form usually employed to signify your *started-and-finished in the past* is the **simple past**.

> I ate dinner.

This says nothing about what went before or came after. It is a complete 'historical' action, what grammarians call *perfective* (not 'perfect').

The **perfect** constructions in English signify something different. Although they name actions which occurred in the past, they define that past action as still relevant at a later time, as causing a state which endures into that later time.

The **present perfect** construction employs the **present** form of *HAVE* to signal that the later time is **now**, *Speech Time*, the time when you speak or write the sentence. You use this construction to describe your **present** state:

> I **have eaten** dinner (*so I**'m** not hungry **now*** or *so I **can** see you immediately without having to eat dinner first*, or whatever the consequence is).

The **past perfect** construction employs the **past** form of *HAVE* to signal that the later time is **then**, *Reference Time*, the 'historical' time defined in the sentence's larger context by your use of simple past forms. You use this construction to describe your state at that time:

> I **had eaten** dinner (*so I **was**n't hungry **then***).

Note that **perfect** constructions require a context. The context for using the **present perfect** construction need not be specified: it 'defaults' to the present, *Speech Time*. But you use the **past perfect** ***only*** when you are narrating past events: a *Reference Time* must be established by using one or more past forms.

Employing the present perfect makes a statement about *Speech Time*, the present.
Employing the past perfect makes a statement about *Reference Time*, a specific point in the past.

Note also that because the present perfect construction is a statement about the present, you are not permitted to use it with an adverbial referring to a point in the past:

> <sup>✲</sup> I **have eaten** dinner yesterday.  *This must be expressed as*
>    I **ate** dinner yesterday.

---

> <sup>✲</sup> *marks a usage as unacceptable*